# How to get moving average of every n values

Tags: r, moving-average

I have a dataframe like this

```
date <- c("2020-09-01","2020-09-01","2020-09-01","2020-09-02","2020-09-02","2020-09-02","2020-09-03","2020-09-03","2020-09-03","2020-09-04","2020-09-04","2020-09-04")
group <- c("red","green","yellow","red","green","yellow","red","green","yellow","red","green","yellow")
number <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
df <- data.frame(date, group, number)
```

I want to group by 'group', and have a new column called 'moving average', which is the average of the 1st and 2nd values, then the average of 2nd and 3rd values, then average of 3rd and 4th values, etc. Then another new column called 'stdev', which is the standard deviation of the previous 2 moving average values. (**In my real word example, I need to have freedom to average consecutive of not just 2 values, but 30)**

I want the output to be like this:
[image]

Thank you so much for your help in advance!!

Comment: You question says average of consecutive values but your pic says average of 1 and 4, 5 and 8. Which one you need? And by values, are you referring to "number" column?

Comment: It is average of consecutive values per 'group'. The average of 1 and 4 is for 'red' group, and average of 5 and 8 is for 'green' group. Yes I'm referring to 'number' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` approach, assuming your data is already arranged by date:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    `moving average` = (number + lag(number)) / 2,
    stdev = abs(`moving average` - lag(`moving average`))/sqrt(2)
  )
```

base r approaches exist but are a little more involved.

Comment: Thanks! This works for my example! One problem I have is that in my real example, it's not only consecutive of 2 values, but it is 30 values. So I think 'lag' doesn't work for consecutive of 30 values.  Can you point me how to modify the code to fit my purpose? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, can you please help me with this? I like the dplyr approach, I want to know how to modify the code to take average of consecutive 30 values.